# Data sharing between different windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a WPF application to configure data acquisition from different types of sensors using DAQ cards. My first window takes input from user regarding different parameters and I would like to use these in all my further windows. What is the best way to store all these.

1. make a separate class and store them all as static fields in the class.
2. store them in a string array in my `mainwindow` class.

Comment: If you want to do it the right way; take a look at the MvvM pattern: - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel
- Introduction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple
- A nice toolkit for it is Mvvmlight ( http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com ) Google "mvvm" for more info ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't follow any of the suggested patterns and you need some properties available across all the windows of your application, you can use the `Application.Properties` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.properties

Answer (score 1):

Tom Deleu is right, you should separate your view from your data. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) is quite powerful and easy to learn too. Is also has quite a few users so any questions are likely to be solved. Whatever you choose, do it the right way.