# Retrieving Property from another WPF form

Tags: wpf

I am a beginner in WPF and trying to learn,So Sorry for this type of query.

I have added a property named **GetName** in WPF Form1 as below:

```
public string GetName
{
    get { return this.uname.Text; }
    set { this.uname.Text = value; }
}
```

Trying to retrieve the GetName property in WPF Form2 as below:

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Form1 mn = new Form1 ();
    MessageBox.Show(mn.GetName.ToString());
}
```

But I am getting prompt with blank. What I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: WPF + form? Why would you do that? Also, you seem to lack the most basic principles in programming. You should consider to look at previous lessons and make sure you understand them. Answers on "How to share data between windows" can be easily found on Google and here, without any problem. Just do the research...

Comment: I mean 2 WPFs(2 .xaml pages).

Comment: For instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453818/data-sharing-between-different-windows-in-wpf , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433935/passing-data-between-wpf-forms , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771872/what-is-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-a-wpf-window-and-its-user-controls ....

Answer (score 1):

You create a new Form:

```
Form1 mn = new Form1 ();
```

Then you request the `Text` value of what I assume is a `TextBox` control to be shown in a `MessageBox`:

```
MessageBox.Show(mn.GetName.ToString());
```

I would not expect `GetName`to return a value, as when a `TextBox` control is created, unless specified, it will not have a value.

Between creating the `Form` and showing the `MessageBox`, you do not show your `Form`, for example:

```
mn.Show();
```

You need to show your `Form` first, input a value into your `uname` control and **then** request its value.

Calling `ToString()` on `GetName` is redundant, just use:

```
MessageBox.Show(mn.GetName);
```